# What is type of data angular sending?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

What is type of data angular sending? I use laravel + angular. I`m trying, but this script return 405 error. Method not allowed.

```
.controller('adminCtrl', function( $scope, $http ){

    $scope.collection = [];
    $scope.newData = [];

    $scope.newrecord = function() {

    $scope.collection.push($scope.newData);

    $http({
      url: '/newrecord',
      method: "POST",
      data: $.param($scope.collection),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
      }
    }).success(function(data){
      console.log(data);
    })

  }

})
```

Comment: sounds like laravel route issue not angular

Comment: You don't have a POST in your backend

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `405 - Method not Allowed` because the server you are sending your request does not have `POST` it the white list of methods allowed to be used to perform requests to that given API.

It's not an angularJS issue, it's a server configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

$http sends data as json.

You do not need to serialize params using "$.param", data is plain javascript object, which is send to your REST endpoint.

So attach just "$scope.collection) and do not set Content Type manually, it is json by default.

POST can be send also with convenience method.

```
$http.post('/someUrl', data, config).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```